# Selecting sharepoint elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, jquery-selectors

I have two radio boxes and I was having trouble making them readonly so I decided to disable the one option that was not checked. I tried "getting" the element using jquery and the information i got on the radio boxes from the console. However, it didn't work. I've never really written Jquery so I'm having trouble finding the mistake.

```
//priority - disable unchecked radiobox
var high = $("input[value='ct101']");
var reg = $("input[value='ct100']");

if(reg.checked == true){
    high.disabled=true;
}else{
    reg.disabled=true;
}
```

Regular Radiobox

```
<input id="ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00"
type="radio" 
value="ctl00" 
disabled="true" 
name="ctl00$m$g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab$ctl00$ctl05$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons"
>
```

High Radiobox

```
<input id="ctl00_m_g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab_ctl00_ctl05_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" 
type="radio" 
name="ctl00$m$g_0537f4e9_69aa_409a_b5ed_15e3624efeab$ctl00$ctl05$ctl02$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons" 
value="ctl01" 
checked="checked"
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reg` is a jQuery wrapper reference, not a dom reference so it does not have `checked` property instead you can test it for against the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector using [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

you need to check

```
if(reg.is(':checked') == true){
    high.disabled=true;
}else{
    reg.disabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here variables `high` and `reg` are jquery wrapper objects and not regular dom objects.

The problem with your code is that the properties `.checked` and `.disabled` are available for dom objects and not on jquery wrapper objects.

To achieve what you are trying to do, use below code instead:

```
if(reg.is(':checked') == true){
    high.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
}else{
    reg.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
}
```

For more information on jquery specific stuff on:

1. check if a checkbox is checked -> refer [this link](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/03/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-using.html)
2. disable/enable control -> refer [this link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2008/12/how-to-disableenable-element-with.html)

Hope this is helpful !!